# for loop logic in matlab / octave incrementing

Tags: matlab, for-loop, octave

I have two lines where **ii** should increment 1:12

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12

```
for ii=1:6
    ii %line1
    ii+1 %line2
end
```

Instead I get **ii**
1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 6 6 7

Ps:  I need to use two lines in the for loop due to functions being called from these lines and filenames are created based on **ii** variable

Comment: As far as I know, you can't modify a loop variable inside its own loop in MATLAB. You could try using `for ii=1:2:12` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need two lines, try:

```
for ii=1:6
  ii*2-1  
  ii*2    
end
```